# Base for Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have problem with one assignment and I am pretty sure that it's not that hard. So, I have 4 vectors :

$$
v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 1 \\ 1
     \end{pmatrix},
  v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\ 3 \\ 1
     \end{pmatrix},
  v_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ -2 \\ 0
     \end{pmatrix},
  v_{4} =\begin{pmatrix}
    -2 \\ 1 \\ -1      
      \end{pmatrix} 
$$

and I have to find **one** base for the $span\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4} \}$. Problem is that every combination of 3 vectors is linearly dependent (also all 4 are linearly dependent).

Have I misunderstood something or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It can very well happen that a basis for $\langle\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}\rangle$ has only two vectors. If you're thinking it must have three vectors for no good reason, then you misunderstood something.

Comment: Sharpening Git's comment: do you want a basis for the subspace spanned by the given vectors or for the whole space (I guess it is $\;\Bbb R^3\;$) ?

Comment: By the way, are you trying to find a basis for the $span\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4} \}$? If so, you can try all four and see if they are linearly independent, if not eliminate one, and see if those three are linearly independent. Continue...

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question now, yes I mean as $$span\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4} \}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice first that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent since they are not collinear i.e. there's not $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ such that $v_1=\lambda v_2$. Now since $v_3=v_1-v_2$ and $v_4=-2v_1+v_2$ so we can't extend the family $(v_1,v_2)$ on a basis for $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Ok, I see. But is there any more general solution I can apply, for example if I get something similar on my test (with I doubt) ?

Comment: The general method is to begin by two linearly independent vectors and then try to extend the family of these two vectors on a linearly independent family as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one general method that involves matrix reduction (I assume you've covered that?)

Set up the matrix: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then use column reduction:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & -3 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
The nonzero columns will then span your space.

That is $\text{span}(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4) = \text{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right)$.  So one of the infinite number of bases of your space is $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$.

Comment: this technique about packing vectors into a matrix has a specific name for it ?

Comment: @user2485710 Not that I'm aware.

Comment: why you deleted your previous comment ? It was a nice read. Anyhow my problem is that in many books and papers that I found there is a lot of mishmosh of words to explain just that and many times I read several lines of text to discover that everything was about this rather simple technique .

Comment: @user2485710 I decided that it was too long for a comment.  If you'd like me to explain it again, then just ask a new question about when and why this method works.